# Do I need to activate something before try_files becomes functional?

Tags: nginx

**Question:** Do I need to activate something before `try_files` becomes functional?

Below is the `nginx.conf` file that I'm using for testing.

I've already checked the following:

**A)** Permissions are set properly.

**B)** SELinux is set properly

**C)** error.html is in the root directory next to index.html.

When I type the wrong url, for example *www.mywebsite.com/asdf.htm* it throws a 404 error and doesn't display error.html.  If I include `=404` in `try_files` I get the same result.  Thanks for any help in advance!  I'm sure I must be missing something obvious but I can't see it.

```
events {}

http {

    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen        80;
        server_name   mywebsite.com;
        server_tokens off;
        root          /www/html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri error.html;
        }
    }

}
```

---

**Addendum**

Permissions on error.html

`-rwxr-xr-x. first first unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 error.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `/error.html`. The leading `/` is missing. I'm not sure exactly what the behavior is when that happens, but it's clearly not what you want.

Comment: you are 100% correct. `try_files $uri /error.html =404;` That works! I'm watching a tutorial on Udemy and in the slide the instructor didn't include the / before the filename. I was pulling my hair out! Thanks so much!